# Webpack using [name] for output.library with multiple entry points

Tags: angular, webpack, umd

I'm trying to output two libraries from my entry points but I seem to be unable to use [name] for output.library much like output.filename. I've also tried putting it into an array per webpack docs (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library#webpackconfigjs): `library: ['[name]'],`.

```
entry: {
  ng: './prod/angular.js',
  Rx: './prod/rxjs.js'
},
output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   filename: '[name].js',
   library: '[name]',
   libraryTarget: 'umd',
   umdNamedDefine: true
},
```

With the config above my files show up under dist in my editor but not in the browser and are missing from root. How do I correctly set up this config to output multiple libraries under different names?

Comment: at a guess the path of 'dist' in  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') is wrong and needs to be set to the root of your website